# How to check an entity has been referred by other before delete it

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In entity framework, how do i know an object has been referred by other? (their relationship is corresponding foreign constraint in database.)

Comment: what do you mean by "referred"? can you give an example?

Comment: In my edmx file have two objects is A and B. B have a association to A (the association was generated automatically by foreign key constraint between table A and table B in database).

Comment: ...and, what is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The entity being referred by the other would be an aggregate (member variable) in the other entity. At least that's how code-first would do it.

Comment: I describe my case as follows: in database there are some tables have foreign-key constraint, example: table B, table C, Table D... have foreign-key constraint to table A. I'm using entity framework to work with database. Now if I want to delete a record in table A i must make sure that record has not been used in another tables so I want to ask in entity framework how do I detect the record has been used in another table or not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your FK constraint to `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. Then delete as usual in the EF. You'll get an exception and the delete will fail if the referring table has a reference to that record.

Comment: Does .Net framework have an exception intend for this case? I am afraid of the exception is used for different errors.

Comment: You get a generic "provider failed" exception wrapped around a provider-specific `InnerException`, which might have an error code, depending upon your provider.